# storage inspector firefox local storage edit JSON error

Tags: json, local-storage, firefox-developer-tools

I am working with an online game that allows editing of its code for testers and / or customers who want to mess around on a private level. The game is called Choice of Game: Rebels Uprising. It is a text based game where you build a character and the story/character change based on your decisions. I am trying to test different things and I am having trouble editing the stats which would allow me to easily control testing different options of play. I got this method from their approved forums and have used it on multiple games. However this one has been very tricky and refuses to work.

Once I open Storage Inspector, I normally can go right to local storage and select the data to change, and then refresh the page to enter the changes.

For this game, I have to go to session storage, select the only option there, then go back to local storage which then reveals the data I wish to change. Otherwise it is invisible. The following pops up and what I would like to change:

`{"version":"12169","stats":{"fname":"Balin","lname":"de Brackii","orig_lname":"de Brackii","epithet":"","liebreaker":false,"openhanded":false,"eclect":false,"slur":"","shameveined":false,"filthborn":false,"childkiller":false,"alias":"","crest":"Great Elder Tree","wisard":"Theurge","wisardry":"Theurgy","wisardric":"Theurgic","aristo":true,"helot":false,"female":false,"male":true,"femalepref":true,"malepref":false,"acepref":false,"aropref":false,"kuria":"Captain","milady":"Captain","he":"he","him":"him","his":"his","hers":"his","woman":"man","girl":"boy","sister":"brother","daughter":"son","ruth":32,"skep":24,"natl":46,"ruthreal":32,"skepreal":24,"natlreal":54,"cha":"1","com":"0","int":"2","wealth":35,"loot":"0","followers":336,"kids":178,"nonkids":158,"dead":"0","kidsdead":"0","sa_foll":"12","sc_foll":"21","needfood":88,"foodstore":10,"mules":"4","sickmules":0,"freemules":4,"arms":10,"blood":4,"usedblood":"0","theurgy":"1","theu_spread":"0","theuknown":"0","religion":"0","literate":"10"`

I tested by simply editing mules and freemules from 4 to 34. I then tried exiting tab and reopening and it, as well as just refreshing the page and both times I get this error:

> JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 1003 of the JSON data

I have even tried editing the temp one as well before closing/refreshing and this did the same thing.

Ideally, I would like to be able to change the wealth, the mules, the arms, and data like that. Please advise on how to correct/avoid this error. Thank you!

https://www.choiceofgames.com/rebels/#utm_medium=web&utm_source=ourgames

Comment: Your posted JSON is not in correct format, can you post whole JSON here? also you can test with simple JSON, for ex. `{ "name": "John Doe" }`

Comment: I apologize, my experience with this is maybe a few hours and that is just figuring things out. The info is visible sometimes, and sometimes it's not and I don't seem to have any control over that. What I posted is what I have been able to find after accidentally discovering it. I have no control over when this information is visible, the method mentioned above is how it occurred last time. From what I have read, firefox tool inspector converts the actual code to another format and vice versa. Is there a way to see all of the hidden files in local storage or to post screenshots on this forum?

Comment: If I got you correctly, you can use `localStorage.getItem('KEY')` to get the value

Comment: From what I get from your description, two things are wrong. First, you expect the data to be stored in the local storage, though you have to go to the session storage first to see it. That *might* be a bug in the DevTools, though without a test case it's hard to say. Second, the JSON you show is incomplete (missing a closing curly brace) and that's the reason you can't save it back. If that's what you get from the DevTools, it *might* be another bug there. If not, you store the data incorrectly.